# bootsrap footer sticker with gwt uibiner

Tags: gwt, twitter-bootstrap, uibinder

I'm trying to get the BS sticker footer as in this example http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer.html
I added the css and html to my gwt Uibinder xml file but it seems the wrap css selector has no effect. I’m not sure if this is b/c i need to redefine the css elements that will be included under 'wrap' div. I'm not sure why the BS sticker footer in GWT doesn't work . do you have a GWT uibinder example of a BS sticker footer?

---UPDATE---

```
 <!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
    <ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
        xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
        <ui:style >

    /* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
      #wrap {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
        /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
        margin: 0 auto -30px;
      }
    #footer {
        min-height: 40px;
 /* padding-left:250px;*/

  background-color: #f2f2f2;


      }
      /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
      #push, #footer {
        height: 30px;
      }
       /* Custom page CSS
      -------------------------------------------------- */
      /* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

      .container2 {
        width: auto;
        max-width: 680px;
      }
       .credit {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width:580px;
      }

#main
{
overflow:auto;
padding-bottom:150px; /* this needs to be bigger than footer height*/
}





        </ui:style>
        <g:HTMLPanel >
    <!-- Part 1: Wrap all page content here -->

             <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
              <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </a>
              <a class="brand" href="#">GND</a>
              <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#browseinfo">Search</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#maintain">Maintain</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#add">Add Data</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <!-- <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul> -->
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- <form class="navbar-form pull-right">
                  <input class="span2" type="text" placeholder="Email"></input>
                  <input class="span2" type="password" placeholder="Password"></input>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
                </form> -->
                    <form class="navbar-search pull-right">
                    <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search"></input>
                    </form>
              </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="main" class="container clear-top">

          <!-- Main hero unit for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
    </div>
          <div class="well well-small">
            <h2 align="center">Welcome To The Geospatial Network Database!</h2>
            <p align="center">This is a demo for gwt and Bootsrap library integration</p>
            <!-- <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p> -->
          </div>

          <!-- Example row of columns -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="span3">
              <h2>How It works</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" rel="popover" href="#" data-original-title="A Title" >View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
              <h2>Who It Is For</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
           </div>
            <div class="span3">
              <h2>Get Support</h2>
              <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
              <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
              <h2>Find Out More</h2>
              <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
              <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
          <div class="span6">
          <div class="well">
              <ul class="nav nav-list" ui:field="recentDocumentList">
        <li class="nav-header">What's New</li>
         <!-- <li class="active" ui:field='moreItem'><a href="#"></a></li> -->
         <!--
        <li><a href="#">Document2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Document3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Document4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Document5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Document6</a></li> -->

        </ul>
        </div>
          </div>
          <div class="span6">
          <div class="well">
          <h2>Section</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <!-- <p>&nbsp;</p> -->
             <!--  <br></br> -->
              <p>
               <!-- <a class="btn btn-primary" id="myButton" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" rel="popover" href="#" data-original-title="A Title">Click to toggle popover</a> </p> -->
              <g:Button  styleName="btn btn-primary"  ui:field="myButton">Click to toggle popover &raquo;</g:Button>  </p>
          </div>
          </div>


         </div>



        </div> <!-- /container -->
       <div id="push"></div> 
        </div>

         <footer>

            <p align="center" >&copy; 2012 <a href="">Ian Mayo </a> and <a href="">othman El Moulat</a>.</p>

         </footer>

        </g:HTMLPanel>
    </ui:UiBinder>
```

Comment: Post a code snippet that you used in Ui:Binder.

Comment: included code in update.